# Laravel 5.1 ERROR: FatalErrorException in Model.php line 852: Class 'App\Fornecedor' not found

Tags: laravel

boa tarde!

estou tentando relacionar duas tabelas: Servicos e Fornecedores, seguem os modelos criados:

**Model Servico**

```
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Servico extends Model
    {
        protected $table = 'servicos';

        protected $fillable = [
            'nomeServico',
            'id_fornecedor'
        ];

        public function fornecedores(){
            return $this->belongsTo("App\Fornecedor");
        }
    }
```

**Model Fornecedor**

```
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Fornecedor extends Model
    {
        protected $table = 'fornecedores';

        protected $fillable = [
            'id',
            'nomeFornecedor'
        ];

        public function servicos(){
            return $this->hasMany('App\Servico');
        }

    }
```

Desta forma estou tentando executar o seguinte procedimento dentro do ServicoController:

```
    public function view($id){
            $servico = Servico::find($id);
            return view('servico.view',['servico'=>$servico]);
    }
```

Na view estou utilizando o seguinte código:

```
    @extends('layout.principal')
    @section('conteudo')
    <h1>Id Serviço #{{$servico->id}}</h1>
    Serviço: {{$servico->nomeServico}}<br/>
    Fornecedor: {{$servico->fornecedores->nomeFornecedor}}<br/>
    @stop
```

e tenho o seguinte erro:

```
    FatalErrorException in Model.php line 852: Class 'App\Fornecedor' not found
```

Nesta tela de erro os dados ID e nomeServico são exibidos corretamente, porém o erro acima aparece na exibição do nome do fornecedor.

Alguém pode me dar uma luz??

Comment: Tentou tirar o `App\` ?

Comment: Sim, tentei tirar o App, mas também não foi cara... pelo que tenho pesquisado o problema está relacionado ao namespace, mais ainda não sei como resolver ....

Comment: Tem algum arquivo seu chamado `FornecedorController` ?

Comment: Sim, mas ainda não possui nenhum método pois estou implementando primeiro a ServicoController.

Comment: Tenta colocar no **Model** `Servico.php`, um namespace assim lá no começo do código: `use App\Fornecedor;`. Faltou o ponto e vírgula...

Comment: nada também... tentei também alterar a minha namespace com o `php artisan app:name protocolo` e coloquei no Model Servico o `use protocolo\Fornecedor`. tentei de tudo aqui e nada rs. acredito que seja uma configuração no laravel ou uma coisa muito tosca

Comment: mudei o retorno do Model Servico para `return $this->belongsTo('protocolo\Fornecedor');`

agora o erro é outro:

`Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\protocolo\resources\views\servico\view.blade.php)`

Comment: É porquê nessa linha: `return view('servico.view',['servico'=>$servico]);`, você tem que por assim: `return view('servico.view')->withServico($servico);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Junior Morais

Tenha certeza de que os Models estão na raiz da pasta "app"
depois basta colocar

```
namespace App;
```

Nos Models Servico e Fornecedor antes da linha:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
```

**Detalhe:** Caso seus models estejam em alguma pasta que não seja a "app" isso vai ter q ser ajustado no namespace citado acima.

Espero que ajude.